# ByteBuffer and FileChannel reading only the specified number of bytes

Tags: java, file-io, nio, bytebuffer, filechannel

I have a situation where in I keep reading with a ByteBuffer as below.

```
 ByteBuffer buffer = MappedByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Constants.BUFFER_SIZE);
```

But when the reading reaches the boundary (when the remaining bytes to read is less than BUFFER_SIZE) I need to read only the `boundaryLimit - FileChannel's current position` .

Means the boundary limit is x and current positions is y, then  I need to read bytes from `y` till `x` and not beyond that.

How do I achieve this ?

I dont want to create another instance with new capacity.

Comment: What do you mean by "*when the reading reaches the boundary*"?

Comment: There's a limit upto which only the read should continue. The bytes after that shouldn't be read. That limit is the boundary. Updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its misleading to use MappedByteBuffer here.  You should use

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Constants.BUFFER_SIZE);
```

If you read less than a full amount of bytes its not a problem

```
channel.read(buffer);
buffer.flip();
// Will be between 0 and Constants.BUFFER_SIZE
int sizeInBuffer = buffer.remaining();
```

EDIT: To read from a random location in a file.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = 
MappedByteBuffer buffer= raf.getChannel()
        .map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, start, length);
```

Comment: Its a very Large file and I dont need the data beyond the upper limit. Actually the intention is to read the data from a specfied start position till specified end position.

Comment: There is a much simpler solution if you want to read/write a random area of a file.  You can make it READ_ONLY or READ_WRITE.

Answer (score 0):

There's no answer to this other than using another API such as a FileInputStream, RandomAccessFile, or MappedByteBuffer. If you have to use a ByteBuffer you will just have to detect the over-read yourself after it happens, and compensate accordingly.